# Behaviour of Carousel Controls and Indicators

Tags: wordpress, controls, carousel, behavior

I have a Wordpress site enhanced with Bootstrap. Using the container and row tags with 1 column, I placed a Carousel with images at 900px wide and 245px high, and everything fell into place. The slides work, and the Controls and Indicators look awesome.

I then moved the Carousel to a different Container, this one with a row containing a col-xx-8 (for the Carousel) and a col-xx-4. I adjusted my CSS so that it reads ".carousel-inner { width: 550px; max-height: auto !important; }". Again, the slides work marvelously.

The problem with the latter arrangement is that the Controls and Indicators go wild on me, and I don't know how to manage the issue. I just want my C&I's to conform to the new width. Something similar as to being responsive to changes in ".carousel-inner" width changes.

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Please provide code/css for your carousel.

Comment: Thanks for your response,  Aibrean. I found my problem once I woke up from stupid. I was placing a container inside a container. Big mistake. Take care!

Comment: @cangrejero So you can either remove your question or add an answer to help others if you think somebody may have same issue.